# how to make a list observable with getx in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I was watching tutorials on using Getx with APIs. after setting a controller for fetching data.
we declared a list variable and made it observable(obs). but the list format was deprecated. can you help me how can i do it now.

```
var products = List<Product>().obs;
```

Answer (score 13):

You can specify the type of the list easily like this

```
var products = <Product>[].obs;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Simply you can create observable model data list like**

```
  List<SampleItem> sampleList = <SampleItem>[].obs;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
RxList<Product> product = (List<Product>.of([])).obs;
```

Comment: @AtmaneAYOUB I have updated my answer please check and let me know if it's working or not

Answer (score 1):

Actually i found the answer for this questions.
This is the new way of declaring a list in flutter after the null safety update :

```
var products = [];
```

And to make it observable with Getx package we do it like this:

```
var products = [].obs;
```

But i dont know how to specify the type of the list in the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list simply like:

```
final listHere = <ListTypeHere>[].obs;
```

A little bit differently from @Wesley's answer is the final which you can use for sake of efficiency since you will be using the *.value*.